# I have a login code but not secured with SharedPreferences

Tags: android

I have this login code where I don't secure it with sharedpreference because I don't know how to use it LOL. Can somebody teach me how to insert it into my code? Thanks. :D

### Login

```
package com.example.kun.carkila;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.AsyncResponse;
import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.PostResponseAsyncTask;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
final String LOG = "MainActivity";
Button btnLogin;
EditText etUsername, etPassword;
TextView tvRegister;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFirstname);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    tvRegister = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegister);


    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            HashMap postData = new HashMap();
            String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
            postData.put("username", username);
            postData.put("password", password);

            PostResponseAsyncTask task1 = new PostResponseAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, postData,
                    new AsyncResponse() {
                        @Override
                        public void processFinish(String s) {

                            if (s.contains("renterowner")) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Renter Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
                                startActivity(in);
                                finish();

                            } else if (s.contains("ownerrenter")) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Owner Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ownerhome.class);
                                startActivity(in);
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }


                        }
                    });
            task1.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/authenticate.php");
        }
    });

    tvRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);

        }
    });
}
}
```

Does my code still have a chance of being secured with a sharedpreference? Thanks a lot if someone helped me. And also how to create a logout? Thaaanks :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use this line of code

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //updated this line
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
// Save to SharedPreferences
editor.putString("username", token);
editor.putString("password", token);
editor.apply();
```

Where you want to save username and password just call this line of code

and where you want to get this data you can use this line of code :

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // update
String username = preferences.getString("username", null);
String password = preferences.getString("password", null);
```

And all this worked for me... You may use this in your app Good luck for your app.

Comment: Where exactly should i write this sir?

Comment: you can use first lines of code where you are getting data from edittext means in ***setOnClickListener*** where you are getting data from edittext when button is clicked.

Comment: and use second code lines ate where you want to fetch data in future...

Comment: And this?  `SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String username = preferences.getString("username ", null);
String password = preferences.getString("password ", null);`
on the pages that redirects after my login?

Comment: whenever you want username and password back then use these lines

Comment: I updated the code and mention the ***//update*** with code lines adding context.MODE_PRIVATE, to make it secure.

Answer (score 0):

Read this page, you should be able to implement it afterwards :)

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#GetSharedPreferences

To be secured, you can specify a context.MODE_PRIVATE, such as:

MODE_PRIVATE
File creation mode: the default mode, where the created file can only be accessed by the calling application (or all applications sharing the same user ID).